# VitualBoxがインストールできない

Tags: windows, centos, virtualbox

VirtualBoxの再インストールができなくなりました。

CentOS7をゲストOSとして使っていたのですが、解像度が変更できなくなり、アンインストールをして再インストールをしたのですが、`VBoxDrv.sysをコピーできません。`と表示されました。

その後も、`VBoxUSBMon.sys`,`VBoxAdp6.sys`,`VBoxNetLwf.sys`がコピーできないとなって、リブートし、CentOSを起動すると、`NtCreatFile(¥Device¥VBoxDrvStub)failed:0xc0000034`がメッセージがでて、先に進めなくなりました。

対処方法を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

OS: Windows 7
VirtualBox: 5.12

Answer (score 0):

再インストールの対象が仮想マシンではなく「VirtualBox」アプリ本体だとして、

- 管理者権限でインストール/アンインストールを行っているか確認してください。
- もう一度インストーラを起動してみてください。インストールされている状態なら「Repair(修復)」「Remove(削除)」の選択肢が出るはずなので、どちらかを実行してみてください。